# Button Programming in a Tab Bar Navigation App

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have an application that has 4 views that are toggled by Tab Bar navigation. The first view (Tab bar Item 1) has a button on its view that when clicked, needs to move the user to the 2nd view (Tab bar item #2). What are the steps needed to do such a thing?

Here is a screenshot of the button and as you can see, nothing has been attached yet. Would love to know the best way to hook up this button either through IB or code.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would use a custom button to replicate the functionality of the button in the tab-bar, but in a nutshell what you need to do is:

1. Link the "Touch Up Inside" outlet to an `IBAction` method in the view-controller for the first tab-bar item (just click and drag from the circle up to "File's Owner", which should be your view-controller class).
2. In the method implementation, simply call `[myTabBarController setSelectedViewController: tab2Controller]` (alternately you can use `[myTabBar setSelectedIndex:1]` to do the same thing).

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks, aroth! The button click will take the user to a specific detailview of a tableview, related to the content in view 1

Answer (score 0):

You need four IB actions you need to link each button to each action, and each action does the work of changing the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Just hook the buttons Touch Up Inside to a method in your Code.
In this method you just do

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; //Index 1 = 2nd Tab
```

and it will switch to your 2nd Tab

Answer (score 0):

Create an action that you hook up the button preferably on "Touch Up Inside":

In .h file:

```
- (IBAction)readAboutItButtonTouched:(id)sender;
```

In .m file:

```
- (IBAction)readAboutItButtonTouched:(id)sender {

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```